# Is there a way to view what commands are being executed by TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Is there a way to view what commands are being executed by TortoiseSVN? There are a few things that I'd like to write a hook for on check-in that I only know how to do in Tortoise. It would be helpful if I could see what commands Tortoise was executing to create my hooks.

Comment: You can just get the TSVN sources, compile them and insert whatever tracing you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TSVN does not call the command line client. So there usually is no exact equivalent.
But, there's [this chapter](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli.html) in the docs, and the progress dialog shows you the command and parameters in plain text as the first line.

Comment: I'm looking for this too. Since TSVN doesn't do this, can recommend a decent SVN GUI that does?